# How can I remove a key and its value from an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

Given an associative array:

```
array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", ...)
```

How would I go about removing a certain key-value pair, given the key?

Answer (score 439, accepted):

You can use [`unset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
unset($array['key-here']);
```

**Example:**

```
$array = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
print_r($array);

unset($array['key1']);
print_r($array);

unset($array['key2']);
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)
Array
(
    [key2] => value2
)
Array
(
)
```

Comment: +1: Thanks for the help. PHP newb here, but it's worth noting that if you are trying to perform these edits inside of a `foreach` loop, then you need to prepend an ampersand to your enumeration variable to allow write access.

Comment: Here is a link to a solution that illustrates the comment by @FreeAsInBeer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617643/9090980) with respect to the ampersand.

Comment: Is this destructive of the original array? Is there a clean functional paradigm way to do this that produces an entirely new array without the value?

Comment: What is the best approach for case insensitivity (key1, Key1, KEY1 etc.)?

Answer (score 33):

Use this function to remove specific arrays of keys without modifying the original array:

```
function array_except($array, $keys) {
  return array_diff_key($array, array_flip((array) $keys));   
}
```

First param pass all array, second param set array of keys to remove.

For example:

```
$array = [
    'color' => 'red', 
    'age' => '130', 
    'fixed' => true
];
$output = array_except($array, ['color', 'fixed']);
// $output now contains ['age' => '130']
```

Comment: you need to close your quotes on `$output = array_except($array_1, ['color', 'fixed']);`

Comment: plus one! functional!

Comment: I needed reverse functionality, is there in built functionality?
```php 
function array_extract($array, $keys) {
  return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip((array) $keys));   
} 
$output = array_extract($array, ['color', 'fixed']);
print_r($output); //Array ( [color] => red [fixed] => 1 );
 ```

Answer (score 27):

Use [`unset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
unset($array['key1']);
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `unset`:

```
unset($array['key1'])
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider this array:

```
$arr = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", "key3" => "value3", "key4" => "value4");
```

- To remove an element using the array `key`:

  ```
  // To unset an element from array using Key:
  unset($arr["key2"]);
  var_dump($arr);
  // output: array(3) { ["key1"]=> string(6) "value1" ["key3"]=> string(6) "value3" ["key4"]=> string(6) "value4" }
  ```
- To remove element by `value`:

  ```
  // remove an element by value:
  $arr = array_diff($arr, ["value1"]);
  var_dump($arr);
  // output: array(2) { ["key3"]=> string(6) "value3" ["key4"]=> string(6) "value4" }
  ```

read more about array_diff: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

- To remove an element by using `index`:

  ```
  array_splice($arr, 1, 1);
  var_dump($arr);
  // array(1) { ["key3"]=> string(6) "value3" }
  ```

read more about array_splice: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Answer (score 4):

You may need two or more loops depending on your array:

```
$arr[$key1][$key2][$key3]=$value1; // ....etc

foreach ($arr as $key1 => $values) {
  foreach ($values as $key2 => $value) {
  unset($arr[$key1][$key2]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do it using Laravel [helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#arrays):

first helper, method [Arr::except](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-except):

```
$array = ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100];

$filtered = Arr::except($array, ['price']);

// ['name' => 'Desk']
```

second helper: method [Arr::pull](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-pull)

```
$array = ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100];

$name = Arr::pull($array, 'name');

// $name: Desk

// $array: ['price' => 100]
```