# Add a prefix to each item of a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, prefix, implode

I have a PHP array of numbers, which I would like to prefix with a minus (-). I think through the use of explode and implode it would be possible but my knowledge of php is not possible to actually do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Essentially I would like to go from this:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

to this:

```
$array = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Simple:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
   $value *= (-1);
}
unset($value);
```

Unless the array is a string:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = '-' . $value;
}
unset($value);
```

Comment: Nice. The pass by reference is essential.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai Essential, but also very dangerous. You should always deactivate the referenced variable: `foreach ($array as &$value){ /* ... */ } unset($value);`.

Comment: @PeterAjtai Good catch, even though this has 57 votes I went ahead and updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Why is it dangerous?

Comment: @mgutt Because PHP doesn't have block level variable scopes. If you use a variable with the same name later in the code, it will magically overwrite the content of the referenced variable.

Comment: How can an array be a string (a scalar)? Do you mean that the array *contains* strings?

Answer (score 172):

An elegant way to prefix array values (PHP 5.3+):

```
$prefixed_array = preg_filter('/^/', 'prefix_', $array);
```

Additionally, this is more than three times faster than a `foreach`.

Comment: I find this the best answer mainly while it's so much faster. Also worth mentioning is [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), it does roughly the same but it always returns a same-sized array with the unmodified item for items that doesn't match the regex. It's also a bit lighter on the version requirements (exists in PHP4 vs `preg_filter` which requires PHP >= 5.3.0).

Comment: is there any way to add a suffix?

Comment: @Avik To add a suffix just use the `$` anchor: `preg_filter('/$/', '_suffix', $array);`

Comment: For more information about regular expressions in PHP read the PCRE manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: thanks, i figured this out `preg_filter('/^(.*?)$/', '$0*', $array)`, it does work, but i like yours, it is short. thanks again really appreciate the help :)

Comment: This is awesome. It should definitly be the accepted answer for so many reasons. It is faster than a `foreach`, it moves the cyclomatic complexity to the internal sub-level of PHP and it can be used for prefix, suffix or change any part of the values of your array when you find a pattern to detect where the modification has to be done. I need to keep this function in my mind. Thank you.

Comment: I like this better than any other answers. I formerly use `array_walk` function but now I've changed to this way. Thank you so much!

Comment: can this method use array `key` to be the prefix of the `value`? I know `foreach` & `array_walk` can, but I wonder if this also

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda There are only a few functions in PHP that instantly combine keys with their values (`http_build_query`, for example). To my knowledge PCRE can't do this.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer, but I prefer `preg_replace` by the way.

Answer (score 76):

In this case, [Rohit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617639/add-a-prefix-to-each-item-of-a-php-array/7617643#7617643) is probably the best, but the [PHP array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) can be very useful in more complex situations.

You can use [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to perform a function on each element of an array altering the existing array. [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) does almost the same thing, but it returns a new array instead of modifying the existing one, since it looks like you want to keep using the same array, you should use [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

To work directly on the elements of the array with [`array_walk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), pass the items of the array by reference ( `function(&$item)` ).

Since php **5.3** you can use anonymous function in array_walk:

```
// PHP 5.3 and beyond!
array_walk($array, function(&$item) { $item *= -1; }); // or $item = '-'.$item;
```

[Working example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/bwxm-354t)

If php 5.3 is a little too fancy pants for you, just use [`createfunction()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php):

```
// If you don't have PHP 5.3
array_walk($array,create_function('&$it','$it *= -1;')); //or $it = '-'.$it;
```

[Working example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/h6qw-2zk8)

Comment: How much slower is your method compared to Rohits? I like one-liner so it would be nice to know how much "loss of speed" it will cause.

Comment: For simple numbers is probably faster a loop. Profile it:) In my case I needed to prefix strings before concatenating the whole array and the fastest solution was Array_walk followed by Implode.

Comment: Great solution. If you want to use previous declared var, add use($XXX) before "{ } : 

array_walk($rank, function(&$item) use($cpt) { if ($item >= $cpt) $item += 1; });

Answer (score 28):

Something like this would do:

```
array_map(function($val) { return -$val;} , $array)
```

Comment: Note that this is PHP 5.3+ only (due to the anonymous function), and it returns a new array instead of modifying the existing array (so `print_r($array)` would show `$array` unchanged after the above. - If you assign the returned value to `$array` this'll get the job done nicely.

Answer (score 12):

You can replace "nothing" with a string. So to prefix an array of strings (not numbers as originally posted):

```
$prefixed_array = substr_replace($array, 'your prefix here', 0, 0);
```

That means, for each element of $array, take the (zero-length) string at offset 0, length 0 and replace it the prefix.

Reference: *[substr_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)*

Comment: this is a fantastic and simple solution that answers the question - thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$array=explode(",", ("-".implode(",-", $array)));
//now the $array is your required array
```

Comment: Its a single line solution. What type of explanation do you want ?

Comment: If any of the array contents contains a `,` then the resulting array will have more items than the original. This does work for the OPs case where it is just numbers.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same situation before.

#### Adding a prefix to each array value

```
function addPrefixToArray(array $array, string $prefix)
{
    return array_map(function ($arrayValues) use ($prefix) {
        return $prefix . $arrayValues;
    }, $array);
}
```

#### Adding a suffix to each array value

```
function addSuffixToArray(array $array, string $suffix)
{
    return array_map(function ($arrayValues) use ($suffix) {
        return $arrayValues . $suffix;
    }, $array);
}
```

Now the testing part:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

`print_r(addPrefixToArray($array, 'prefix'));`

#### Result

```
Array ([0] => prefix1 [1] => prefix2 [2] => prefix3 [3] => prefix4 [4] => prefix5)
```

`print_r(addSuffixToArray($array, 'suffix'));`

#### Result

```
Array ([0] => 1suffix [1] => 2suffix [2] => 3suffix [3] => 4suffix [4] => 5suffix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this since PHP 7.4:

```
$array = array_map(fn($item) => -$item, $array);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/lD5tF)