# How to add a prefix before an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP:

```
$pbx01_connection = array("customer/voip_extensions.php");
```

how can i add a prefix and suffix to each item in the array?

for example,

```
$pbx01_connection = '/admin/'.array("customer/voip_extensions.php");
```

so `/admin/` is added before each item in the array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617639/add-a-prefix-to-each-item-of-a-php-array

see the link.

Comment: check this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617639/add-a-prefix-to-each-item-of-a-php-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php
function addPrefix($value)
{
    return '/admin/' . $value
}

$new_array = array_map("addPrefix", $array);
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like a overhead to do such a simple thing. Why not just `foreach ($array as &$value)
    $value = '-'.$value;`

Comment: Modifying values by reference is a bad practice as it can make following data throughout code more difficult.

Comment: @JohnConde It can still be achieved with a simple loop.

Comment: I don't see this as really overly complicated. Especially since this also allows the separation of logic and provides for easily organized code.

Comment: @JohnConde I agree with you. But it's not related to "modifying values by reference".