# array_fill with increasing $i values

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a function like `array_fill`, that lets me fill an array with the same string ("field_"), combined with an increasing $i variable like this:

```
private function fields() {
    $result = [];

    foreach(range(1,44) as $i) {
        $result[] = "field_$i";
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I know there is a bunch of functions in php and I would love to have this in one line (if possible).

Comment: Are those `field_X` column-names for a database perhaps?

Comment: Anytime you see `field_1` `field_2` etc, you should consider an array.

Comment: @Qirel yes they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28115783/4126424), seems to be 3 times faster than foreach and it's the shortest solution I could find so far.

```
$prefixed_array = preg_filter('/^/', 'prefix_', $array);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `array_map` to remove the need for an explicit loop, but I don't think putting it on one line gains you much in terms of readability:

```
$results = array_map(function ($i) { return "field_{$i}"; }, range(1, 44));
```

=

```
Array
(
  [0] => field_1
  [1] => field_2
  ...
```

Comment: you are right, thanks for your response! I was hoping for something shorter.. like a single method call: array_fill($i = 1, 44, "field_$i"); or so :)

Comment: I mean, you've basically got the function you need in the question - just move the prefix and the range parameters into function arguments, and declare it as `array_prefix($from, $to, $prefix)` or something similar. Then you can use it wherever you like as `array_prefix(1, 44, 'field_');`

Answer (score 0):

Php's [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops actually allow you to access the current index

```
private function fields() {
    $result = [];

    foreach(range(1,44) as $k => $i) {
        $result[] = "field_$k";
    }

    return $result;
}
```