# Removing elements from an associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053517/how-can-i-remove-a-key-and-its-value-from-an-associative-array) describes how to remove an element of an associative array with Unset i.e  *unset($array['key1']);*

I have this array:

```
Array
(
[queryLocator] => 
[done] => 1
[records] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 
                [CreatedDate] => 2016-08-28T14:43:45.000Z
                [Leader__c] => GF
                [Location__c] => Postbridge
                [Service_Date__c] => 2016-09-03
                [Service_Time__c] => 14:30
                [Service_Type__c] => Baptism
            )



    )

[size] => 42
[pointer] => 0
[QueryResultsf] => SforceEnterpriseClient Object
    (
        [sforce:protected] => SoapClient Object
            (
                [trace] => 1
                [compression] => 32
                [_encoding] => utf-8
                [_features] => 1
                [_user_agent] => salesforce-toolkit-php/20.0
                [_soap_version] => 1
                [sdl] => Resource id #8                 
        [packageVersionHeader:protected] => 
        [client_id:protected] => 
    )
```

)
)

I want to delete the key [queryLocator], replace the key  [done] with [total], replace the key [records] with [rows] and delete all subsequent keys i.e [size], [pointer] etc.

Using unset,  i.e   *unset($array['queryLocator']);* has no effect.

What am I doing wrong ?  Thanks.

Comment: just use unset($array_values['queryLocator']);

Comment: $array_values is undefined.  Did you mean ?  $result = array($response);
unset(array_values($result['queryLocator']));  This gives
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in (unset line).

Comment: $array_values should be replaced by your array variable name @peter

Comment: Sorry but $result = array($response);
unset($result['queryLocator']); does nothing - no error but the queryLocator key is still present. @jothi

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that achieves what I wanted - taking output from a Sales Force query and formatting it as required by a EasyUI  datagrid.

```
 //--Get the Sales Force Data
 $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

//--Encode and decode - for some reason 
$data = json_encode((array)$response);
$x = json_decode($data,true);

//--Empty Array
$q = array();


//--Add array element for number records 
$q['total'] = $numRecs;
//--Copy the array element from original query with data
$q['rows'] = $x['records'];

//--JSON Encode the new array
$y = json_encode($q);

//--Return the array to Ajax call
echo ($y);
```

And here's a snippet of the validated JSON..

```
 {  
 "total":193,
 "rows":[  
  {  
     "Id":null,
     "CreatedDate":"2016-08-28T14:43:45.000Z",
     "Leader__c":"GF",
     "Location__c":"Postbridge",
     "Service_Date__c":"2016-09-03",
     "Service_Time__c":"14:30",
     "Service_Type__c":"Baptism"
  },
  {  
     "Id":null,
     "CreatedDate":"2016-08-17T20:43:10.000Z",
     "Leader__c":"GF",
     "Location__c":"Ashburton",
     "Service_Date__c":"2016-09-04",
     "Service_Time__c":"08:00",
     "Service_Type__c":"HC 2"
  },
  {  
     "Id":null,
     "CreatedDate":"2016-08-17T20:43:10.000Z",
     "Leader__c":"GF",
     "Location__c":"Bickington",
     "Service_Date__c":"2016-09-04",
     "Service_Time__c":"09:00",
     "Service_Type__c":"HC 2"
  },
  {  
     "Id":null,
     "CreatedDate":"2016-08-17T20:43:10.000Z",
     "Leader__c":"MC",
     "Location__c":"Holne",
     "Service_Date__c":"2016-09-04",
     "Service_Time__c":"10:30",
     "Service_Type__c":"HC 1"
  },
```

I struggled a bit with the array manipulation but it works.  Any code improvement suggestions most welcome !