# How to remove an item from a nested array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a complicated nested array which I want to remove all items and their children with specific store_id:
It's really difficult and I don't know how to figure it out.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [cart_id] => 89
        [product_id] => 46
        [store_id] => 2
        [option] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_option_id] => 92
                        [value] => Aqua
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [product_option_id] => 91
                        [value] => 85C
                    )
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cart_id] => 90
        [product_id] => 46
        [store_id] => 2
    )
```

Many thanks for any kind help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a key and its value from an associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053517/how-can-i-remove-a-key-and-its-value-from-an-associative-array)

Comment: @MohammadTomaraei: probably for you these two are the same, but for me as beginner they're quite different!

Comment: @MohammadTomaraei: I don't understand the down vote. It seems like a reasonable question to ask. For me it's a question and I didn't find any proper answer in google matching with my problem, so what am I missing that makes this question get down votes? Not picking a fight, just curious. Peace.

Comment: @MohammadTomaraei: Just because it's too much easy for a smart person like you, should it be down voted!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove the entire array element if it has a specific store_id, you just need to loop over the array, check the store_id and remove the element if you don't want it anymore.

E.g.:

```
<?php         
    foreach($data as $key=>$row){
        if($row['store_id'] == 2){
          unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }        
?>
```

You can change that '2' to be anything you want to specifically remove a store. Or you could change the if to match an array of ids if you want to match several stores.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example for unsetting the cart_id in multi dimensional array.

```
<?php         
    foreach($data as $key=>$row){
          unset($data[$key]['cart_id']);
    }        
?>
```